# Passing arguments to setup:install?

Tags: sylius

I'm writing a bash script to provision a server for [sylius](https://sylius.com).

When running the installation using:

```
php8 bin/console sylius:install
```

... the installation asks the user what locale, currency and credentials to use.

Is there any way to pass arguments to `sylius:install` so I can automate this step? I have checked through the documentation and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Pass `--no-interaction --fixture-suite=default` option to install default fixtures together with users defined at
  https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/fixtures/shop_configuration.yaml#L154-L175
- OR Create your own fixtures suite with your own users and pass `--no-interaction --fixture-suite=your_suite`
- OR Pass `--no-interaction` and default admin user will be created with next credentials: Login: `sylius`, Password: `sylius`